# React Router history.push in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a page ("/paymentsucess"). In this page, I am using the react-countdown-circle-timer component (https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer#props-for-both-reactreact-native). Upon reaching this page ("/paymentsuccess"), countdown beings. After countdown reaches zero, I want to redirect user back to home page ("/").

To achieve this, for the CountdownCircleTimer component, when onComplete, I set the state initialMount to false.

```
            <CountdownCircleTimer
              onComplete={() => {
                setInitialMount(false);
                return [true, 1500];
              }}
              isPlaying
              duration={2}
              colors={[
                ["#004777", 0.33],
                ["#F7B801", 0.33],
                ["#A30000", 0.33],
              ]}
            >
              {renderTime}
            </CountdownCircleTimer>
```

Given that initialMount is changed, my useEffect (in the paymentsuccess component) will kick in and redirect users to "/". I am using history.push("/") here.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialMount !== true) {
      console.log("On change in status,");
      console.log(initialMount);
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [initialMount, history]);
```

I was able to redirect user back to "/" successfully. But upon reaching "/", they got redirected back to /paymentsuccess again. And then from /paymentsuccess it goes back to / and then the loops continue. Infinite loop.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? :( I need to stop this loop and lands user back to / and stops there.

I am using Router from react-router-dom and createBrowserHistory from history.

Below is the full code for my paymentsuccess component

```
import React, { useEffect, useStatem} from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";

function PaymentSuccess() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [initialMount, setInitialMount] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("On component mount, status is");
    console.log(initialMount);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("On component unmount, status is");
      setInitialMount(true);
      console.log(initialMount);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialMount !== true) {
      console.log("On change in status,");
      console.log(initialMount);
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [initialMount, history]);

  const renderTime = ({ remainingTime }) => {
    if (remainingTime === 0) {
      return <div className="timer">Starting...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="timer">
        <div className="value">{remainingTime}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={0}>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
          <Paper
            className="paymentSuccessLeftPaper"
            variant="outlined"
            square
          ></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
          <Paper className="paymentSuccessRightPaper" variant="outlined" square>
            <h1>Payment Success</h1>
            <CountdownCircleTimer
              onComplete={() => {
                setInitialMount(false);
                return [true, 1500];
              }}
              isPlaying
              duration={2}
              colors={[
                ["#004777", 0.33],
                ["#F7B801", 0.33],
                ["#A30000", 0.33],
              ]}
            >
              {renderTime}
            </CountdownCircleTimer>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PaymentSuccess;
```

I have checked my "/" page and I don't think there is any logic there redirecting to "/paymentsuccess". The page ("/") code is as below.

```
import React from "react";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

function LandingPage() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
      minHeight: "100%",
      padding: theme.spacing(0),
      textAlign: "center",
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={0}>
        <Grid item xs={4} sm={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper} variant="outlined" square>
            <h1>Photo Strips</h1>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
              <Link href="/photo10">SELECT</Link>
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} sm={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper} variant="outlined" square>
            <h1>Photo Strips and GIF</h1>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
              <Link href="/photogif12">
                SELECT
              </Link>
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} sm={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper} variant="outlined" square>
            <h1>Photo Strips and Boomerang</h1>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
              <Link href="/photoboomerang12">
                SELECT
              </Link>
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LandingPage;
```

Thank you all in advance! Appreciate all the help and advise

****UPDATE****

Below is Router code

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";
import Photo10 from "./components/Photo10";
import PhotoGIF12 from "./components/PhotoGIF12";
import PhotoBoomerang12 from "./components/PhotoBoomerang12";
import PaymentSuccess from "./components/PaymentSuccess";

import DynamicLayout from "./router/DynamicLayout";

import { history } from "./helpers/history";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <DynamicLayout
            exact
            path="/"
            component={LandingPage}
            layout="LANDING_NAV"
          />
          <DynamicLayout
            exact
            path="/photo10"
            component={Photo10}
            layout="PHOTO10_PAGE"
          />
          <DynamicLayout
            exact
            path="/photogif12"
            component={PhotoGIF12}
            layout="PHOTOGIF12_PAGE"
          />
          <DynamicLayout
            exact
            path="/photoboomerang12"
            component={PhotoBoomerang12}
            layout="PHOTOBOOMERANG12_PAGE"
          />
          <DynamicLayout
            exact
            path="/paymentsuccess"
            component={PaymentSuccess}
            layout="PAYMENTSUCCESS_PAGE"
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Below is the code for the DynamicLayout component

```
import React from "react";

const DynamicLayout = (props) => {
  const { component: RoutedComponent, layout } = props;

  const actualRouteComponent = <RoutedComponent {...props} />;

  switch (layout) {
    case "LANDING_NAV": {
      return <>{actualRouteComponent}</>;
    }

    case "PHOTO10_PAGE": {
      return <>{actualRouteComponent}</>;
    }

    case "PHOTOGIF12_PAGE": {
      return <>{actualRouteComponent}</>;
    }

    case "PHOTOBOOMERANG12_PAGE": {
      return <>{actualRouteComponent}</>;
    }

    case "PAYMENTSUCCESS_PAGE": {
      return <>{actualRouteComponent}</>;
    }

    default: {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Default Nav</h2>
          {actualRouteComponent}
        </>
      );
    }
  }
};

export default DynamicLayout;
```

Comment: I think your problem is in the "/" page code, did you ckecked if there is some redirect to /paymentsuccess? It seems like you forgot the [ ] brackets there...

Comment: I can't find any issue in the above code. I suspect the problem to be at the router level. could you show your app's routing code?

Comment: @Fresh Done. I have included my "/" code above too. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you changes value of variable in useEffect and that variable also added in useEffect dependency array, So when ever your useEffect change the value due to presence of that variable in dependency array, it again called the useEffect thus a infinite loop occurs

so just remove 'history' variable from your dependency array

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advise. I've removed history in my dependency array. But still error persists. I get redirected back to "/" and then from "/" i go back to "/paymentsuccess" non stop in an infinite loop. Somehow there is something happening at "/" then does the directing back to "/paymentsuccess"....

I am using Redux to manage my state. Could that be a reason?